# Table of Contents dots

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm working on my master thesis, and the Table of Contents looks just fine, except from the dot aligment for chapters. The other chapter and subsections are okay.

[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[  12pt,                % font size
            a4paper,                  % paper size.
            sumario=tradicional,      % traditional toc
            brazil]{abntex2}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont\bfseries} %bold chapter

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents*
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

I think there's something to do with that line that bolds the chapters and for some reason change the aligment

Comment: Did you manipulate the ToC code anywhere? Can you reproduce the error in a minimal example? Try reproducing it. Share that, then you should be able to get some help here.

Comment: try adding very small horizontal space something like `\chapter[Revisão de literatura\kern100sp\relax]{Revisão de literatura}`, varying the `100`, possibly using `-100` and see (after compiling twice) if it changes something. Else without actual fonts used and a mwe reproducing issue it is frustratingly difficult to debug this. By the way, standard `book` class uses no dots for chapter titles.

Comment: Are you using microtype?

Comment: By default the `memoir` class does not use dot leaders for `\chapter` entries in the ToC. Something must have changed this, but who knows what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   \documentclass[  12pt,                     % font size
                a4paper,                  % paper size.
                sumario=tradicional,      % traditional toc
                brazil]{abntex2}

    %Insert TOC % -- não, você NÃO precisa disso! é inútil. 
    %    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{SUMÁRIO}
     %  \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}

    \renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont\bfseries} %bold chapter

 \renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{
 \normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsectiondotsep}}

    \usepackage{blindtext} 

    \begin{document}


        \tableofcontents*
    \blinddocument

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I find these modifiers on ToC (Em português pra vc, meu consagrado haha)

`% Travessão no sumário para apêndices e anexos \\
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill} \\

% Insere espaço entre os itens do sumário de diferentes capítulos \\
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{1.0em \@plus\p@}` \\

Comment: So... as you didn't send us a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) , we cannot even imagine what's causing that...

Comment: A tried to replicate the problem now :)

Comment: There is no problem at all with your MWE. Did you compile it?

Comment: I did, toggle comment on and off on the line I cited, the space between the page number and the dots change, at least for me here.

Comment: Which is "the line you cited" and why didn't you insert it in your MWE? If it's the one above, no, it changes nothing at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79488/discussion-between-lucas-paiva-and-joseph).

Comment: I revised the answer. See if it works for you now. It seems that the problem was the bold dots.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I coudn't compile your revised answer on Overleaf. Where I compile it make any difference?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: That was it, much appreciated!